# Eureka Server - list all registered instances

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I have a Spring Boot application that is also a Eureka Server. I want to list all instances that have been registered to this Eureka Server. How do I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fetch the `registry` using `EurekaServerContextHolder.getInstance().getServerContext().getRegistry()` then use the `registry` to list all `Applications`

```
PeerAwareInstanceRegistry registry = EurekaServerContextHolder.getInstance().getServerContext().getRegistry();
    Applications applications = registry.getApplications();

    applications.getRegisteredApplications().forEach((registeredApplication) -> {
        registeredApplication.getInstances().forEach((instance) -> {
            System.out.println(instance.getAppName() + " (" + instance.getInstanceId() + ") ");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hello, does the EurekaServerContextHolder need inject? Using the same code, I can't get anything in my test class.

Comment: @tyrantqiao did you manage to resolve this, I am facing the same challenge. The code provided by Kihats doesn't work for me.

Comment: @SyCode Sorry for so long to see your question, I'm using another way to get applications now. I would give my solution here.

Comment: @tyrantqiao, you don't need to inject it. In fact this is the javadoc on that class 'A static holder for the server context for use in non-DI cases.'

Comment: what about the response variable inside the println?

Comment: Does not seem to work, nowadays. For me this other answer worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59870571/969483

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, get all services registered on eureka and show iformation about each one

```
@Autowired
private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

public List<ServiceInstance> getApplications() {

    List<String> services = this.discoveryClient.getServices();
    List<ServiceInstance> instances = new ArrayList<ServiceInstance>();
    services.forEach(serviceName -> {
        this.discoveryClient.getInstances(serviceName).forEach(instance ->{
            instances.add(instance);
        });
    });
    return instances;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all registered applications.

1. you need to turn on eureka's configuration.

   ```
   eureka:
     client:
       serviceUrl:
         defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
       #register eureka as application
       register-with-eureka: true
       #fetch all thing, we can get applications here
       fetch-registry: true
       #also you can specify the instance renewal time.
     server:
       enable-self-preservation: false
   ```
2. now we can get the registered applications, but the class must be put in eureka application's package. [As we need to autowire PeerAwareInstanceRegistry]

[image]

```
@Autowired
PeerAwareInstanceRegistry registry;

public void eurekaApplications() {
    Applications applications = registry.getApplications();
    //TODO add your code here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To fetch the list of applications registered in the eureka server, you can use the DiscoveryClient interface from `springframework.cloud.client.discovery` package according to documentation [docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__service_discovery_eureka_clients.html#_alternatives_to_the_native_netflix_eurekaclient).

```
import java.util.List;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.ServiceInstance;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DiscoveryClient{


  private final DiscoveryClient client;

  @GetMapping("/api/discovery/instance/info")
  public ResponseEntity<?> test() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(getApplications());
  }


  public int getApplications() {
    List<ServiceInstance> instances = client.getInstances("YOUR-APPLICATION-NAME-WITHIN-EUREKA");
    log.info("instances {}", instances);
    return instances.size();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One can access the list of registered apps from the registry directly:

```
@Autowired
PeerAwareInstanceRegistry eureka_registry;

List<Application> apps = eureka_registry.getSortedApplications(); 
for(Application a : apps)
{
    System.out.println("  " + a.getName() + ": " + a.getInstancesAsIsFromEureka().get(0).getStatus().name());
}
```