# im using latest version (v2.7.3) my question is how can get the eureka server instances to get my uri?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.3)

List accountslist = eurekaDiscoveryClient.getInstances("ACCOUNTS");
ServiceInstance accounts = accountslist.get(0);
URI accountsMS = accounts.getUri();
this is not working for me cause im using latest version should i degarde or any other ways i could implemnt any one?

appreciated if you could answer!

Comment: @tyrantqiao hi guys I've gone through https://stackoverflow.com/a/42427493/9344429 this but its needed to inject can you help me with that?

Comment: @Kihats https://stackoverflow.com/a/42427493/9344429